# Error in "Extensibility Hands-on Labs for Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0"

Tags: enterprise-library-5, logging-application-block

I was going through the Extensibility Hands-on Labs for Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 and found an error in the "Lab 2: Custom Logging Trace Listener" lesson. It applies to exercises 2,3 and 4 in the lab. I searched through the issues tracker on the CodePlex site but could not anything related to this error.

Overview of the problem:

When attempting to add the trace listener via the Enterprise Library Configuration tool I get a validation error : “The field ListenerDataTypeName is missing a required value”. Therefore the configuration tool will not save the config file.

Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself see the following blog post for full description of fix:

http://mvvmdevotee.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/fixing-an-error-in-extensibility-hands-on-labs-for-microsoft-enterprise-library-5-0/